# How does DSN on Windows 7 resolve the host name?

Tags: sql, odbc, dsn

This is just an informational question, but I was hoping someone out there might have a link to some documentation that shows how this works.

Issue:

Creating a DSN on a Windows 7 (x64) system to a locally installed database server, it will not resolve if using the machine name such as "MyComputer". A timeout error occurs.

If you ping "MyComputer" from the command prompt then you get the correct IP address (::1 / 127.0.0.1).

Solution:

If you add a DNS entry in the hosts file for "MyComputer" (127.0.0.1 MyComputer) then test the DSN it works.

if you use the IP address in the DSN (127.0.0.1) it works.

Question:

Exactly how does Windows 7 resolve the name of the server entered for a DSN?  It looks like it only uses TCP/IP and DNS to resolve it, hence why adding the DNS entry in the hosts file resolves the timeout.

Does anyone have any information to back up this assumption?

Answer (score 0):

Your computer is not called 'mycomputer'
If you right click on the 'my computer' icon and choose properties it will display the Computer Name about a third of the way down the page.

By adding the entry in the host file, 127.0.0.1 MyComputer, you are instructing your pc that if someone pings or explores to mycomputer resolve that name to the address of 127.0.0.1

You could type 127.0.0.1 Mushrooms in the host file and this would work in the same way.

As another example in the host file you could type 173.194.67.106 bananas
Then open a web browser and type bananas, which should then take you to the google web site.

The link below should help you to understand this more.

http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/hosts-files-explained/

Comment: This has nothing to do with my question.  I understand what the real computer name is.  I can rename my computer to "Fubar" and the same thing happens.

My question is how **DSN** (NOT **DNS**) handles looking up the host name you enter for that DSN.  

My assumption is that a DSN does not use computer names, it only uses TCP/IP.  I wanted to confirm this with some documentation.